# Non public shopify app that can populate checkout page with products and discounts?

Tags: shopify

I am trying an experiment and I think I am close to a complete solution.  I would like to do the following.

1. I do not want to modify any of the liquid templates in my shopify site.
2. I want to put a button with the text "Click Me" in the header of my shopify site.
3. When the customer presses "Click Me", they will be taken to the shopify checkout page.  The shopify checkout page must show a quantity of 2 for the product with variant_id 11111111111111 and the checkout page must show that a discount of $X will be applied to the checkout.  The value of X must be a random number between 0 and 100.  The value of X must not be associated with any existing discount codes in the shopify store.
4. This solution must be available to only my store and no other store.

I created a prototype, but the best I could do was satisfy objectives 1-3.  I do not know how to satisfy all 4 objectives.  Is it possible to satisfy all 4 objectives?  If so, what do I need to do?

**Details on my prototype:**

For my prototype I created an unpublished sales channel app called the ProtoApp.  My ProtoApp will use the script_tag.json API endpoint to load a custom javascript file from one of my linux servers.  My custom javascript file will add a new  element to the header of the webpage.  The onclick event of the button will make an ajax call to my ProtoApp .  My ProtoApp will make the following call via BASH on Linux

```
curl -i \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: mytokenfromshopify" \
-X POST "https://mystore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/checkouts.json" \
-d @checkout.json
```

And my checkout.json looks like this

```
{
  "checkout": {
    "line_items": [
      {
        "variant_id": 11111111111111,
        "quantity": 2
      }
    ],
    "applied_discount": {
    "amount": ###autogen##,
    "title": "XYZ Promotion",
    "description": "Promotional item for blackfriday.",
    "value": ###autogen###,
    "value_type": "fixed_amount",
    "non_applicable_reason": null,
    "applicable": true
    }
  }
}
```

Shopify Checkout API will give me a success response.  I will find a `web_url` with a value like  `https://mystore.myshopify.com/402423011/checkouts/2b3e24742ea6c087ec7c10e7c4117bba` in the success response.  I send this `web_url` back to my javascript file and do a `location.href = web_url`, which causes the customer to go to the checkout page.  The customer sees the appropriate discount applied.  The customer can continue with checkout process and payment.  Everything is perfect.

To my current understanding, the problem with this approach is that in order to use it in a production store, I must publish my app to the market.  This means other people other than me will be able to use it.  Hence failure to meet the 4th requirement mentioned above.

Based on my research, a private app will not allow me the write_checkout scope, which to my understanding, is necessary for my solution.

Any suggestions on what I can do to satisfy all 4 objectives?

Comment: If you want an app not in the Shopify store don't publish it there. What is the issue? You can use it as a custom App that is not listed in the store. There isn't much of a difference if the App is published or not. So you install it only from your app URL address. If you want further protection add a password field to the page.

Comment: @drip I can't seem to find an option to install an unpublished sales channel app to a real live store.  It seems unpublished sales channel apps can only be installed on development stores?  And private apps don't allow the `write_checkout` scope.  I'm not familiar with the concept of `custom app` for shopify, and don't see any literature on it.  Let me know if I misunderstood something?